# Generate a json with variable value from a file using bash

Tags: unix

I have a fleet of raspberry pi's running as access points. I set the default SSID and PASSWORD using a simple bash script that runs at boot. I get unique values for this:

SSID = `cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address | tail -c 10 | tr -d ":"`

PW = `cat /proc/cpuinfo | tail -c 9`

I just echo the results on the hostapd file, everything work just fine, each Raspberry Pi get unique SSID and PW. Now I need to generate a JSON file with this values (via bash) in a format like this.

```
{
  "wifi": {
    "ssid": "SSID",
    "pw": "PW"
  }
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Regards

Comment: Depending on the size of your 'fleet' you might find that Ansible gives you a greater level of configuration control than bash scripts alone.

Comment: Hey, Tom, thanks! This is for "LAB" only. We are using Resin.io to get it done, but for now i just need to give the dev team this json with ssid and pw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heredocs perform variable expansion, so you can do something like

```
SSID=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address | tail -c 10 | tr -d ":")
PW=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | tail -c 9)

cat >./config.json <<EOF
    {
      "wifi": {
          "ssid": "$SSID",
          "pw":   "$PW"
      }
    }
EOF
```